# CodeIgniter - Problems with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an app which will check if user is already attended to a certain event and if so,
the only option the app gives is to actually remove that attendance.

However, I'm stuck since the model function needs two parameters to check if user is already attended but I have difficulties to understand
how do I get that event_id from the view to actually check that event_id.

The user_id is simple, since it's been saved in the session. Am I thinking this too way too complicated or what?

**Part of my view:**

```
// In here I check if the user has already attended

<?php if($checkifattending == 0) :?>

<form action='<?=base_url()?>events/participateEvent' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='<?=$event['event_id']?>'/>
    <input type='submit' name='attend_event' value='+' title='Osallistu tapahtumaan' class='medium-button-attend' />
</form>

<?php else:?>
<form action='<?=base_url()?>events/removeAttend' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='event_id' value='<?=$event['event_id']?>'/>
    <input type='submit' name='remove_attend' value='-' title='Peru osallistuminen' class='medium-button-remind' />
</form>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Model to check if user has attended to that specific event:**

```
public function checkifAttending($user_id, $event_id)
{   
    $where = array(
        'userID' => $user_id,
        'eventID' => $event_id
        );


    $this->db->select('eventID')->from('user_events')->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // It will return either 0 or 1 based on if the user is already attended
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**Controller where I'm passing that model function into an array:**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('event_model');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Array to return all the actual events
        $data['events'] = $this->event_model->getAllEvents();

        // How do I retrieve that $event_id value and assign it in this array?
        $data['checkifattending'] = $this->event_model->checkifAttending($this->session->userdata('user_id'), $event_id);


        $this->load->view('/template/header');
        $this->load->view('events', $data);
        $this->load->view('/template/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you facing an issue while rendering the view page?

Comment: Well, yes.. I can load the view of course, but I need to make the check if user is already attending. There are many events and if I just check it with only using that user_id, it will affect all of those events and the app thinks that I've attended all of those events

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have a much easier time if you retrieve the attendance data simultaneously with the events list.

Try making a new model function, getAllEventsWithAttendance($user_id), and select all the events LEFT JOINed to user_events.  This will give you the full event list, plus join data from user_events if it exists.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: That actually makes sense. However I still have problems understanding how to do the actual check if I retrieve all of the data from joined tables? Certainly it will return NULL if there's no attend.

Comment: And why should I use the parameter $user_id if I will retrieve all events, not just those based on a certain condition?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - that's why we want to use a left join.  The left join will select all rows from the first table (events) plus matches from the second table if they exist.  The columns from the second table will be null on rows where there is no match, so in your view, you can test if one of those values is null or not to see if the user is attending each event.

Comment: You need to pass the $user_id so that you can specify it in the WHERE clause on the left join: SELECT * FROM events LEFT JOIN user_events ON events.event_id = user_events.event_id WHERE user_events.user_id = $user_id

Comment: So is the column naming problem then? I need to join three tables together, users, events and user_events.
In users table I have a column 'user_id', in events table I have a column named 'event_id' and in
user_events table two columns, named 'user_id' and 'events_id'. So how will I check it. I certainly can't just write
<?php if($row['event_id'] == NULL) :?> // Then show the attend button and vice versa, because it can't know If i'm referencing
to the event_id in the events table or the event_id in the user_events table?

Comment: You can alias columns if there are any conflicts (SELECT user_events.user_id AS ue_user_id), but you can just test for the existence of either user_id, in this case.  Remember, your result will be a list of ALL events, with the join-table columns populated only when there is a match.

Comment: The problem is that if I use that WHERE clause, it will not join the events other people have created. The thing is to show all the events, including them which I've created.